# invalid constructor and operator

Tags: c++

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    Point() { x = NULL; y = NULL; }
    Point(int x1, int y1) { x = x1;     y = y1; }

    ~Point(void) {  }


    Point & operator= (const Point &p)
    {
        x = p.x;    y = p.y;    return (*this);
    }

    bool operator== (const Point &p)
    {
        return ((x == p.x) && (y == p.y));
    }

    bool operator!= (const Point &p)
    {
        return ((x != p.x) || (y != p.y));
    }
}
```

above code for my Variable type Point

Below here is short code of my cpp

```
Point Finish = ladyrinth->getEndLocation(); // This is to get the coordinate of end location
bool up = true;
bool down = true;
bool left = true;
bool right = true;

if (up == Finish)
        DirectionMove = 0;
    if (down == Finish)
        DirectionMove = 1;
    if (left == Finish)
        DirectionMove = 2;
    if (right == Finish)
        DirectionMove = 3;
```

the error code is no operator "==" match operands, operands are bool to point
but after i try make the operator they say no constructor which i dont know how to make. please help me.

Comment: up/down... is `bool`, but the `==` operator you overloaded required `Point` on both side.

Comment: @JohnZeng i did put the point operator==
    
Point operator== (const Point p)
 {
  return ((x == p.x) && (y == p.y));
 }

but i not sure if it's correct plus there is a error for no constructor for this operator which i dont know how to make one. can u enlighten me?

Comment: You are trying to compare bool's to Points. That won't work unless you have an operator equal that takes a bool. But it appears that there is no way to compare bool's and points so you are attempting the wrong thing.

Comment: Also you don't have any code that shows how a point is supposed to indicate direction.

Comment: You told it how to do `Point == Point`, but not how to do `Point == bool`. Add a function `bool Point::operator ==(bool b) const;` and possibly a `bool operator(bool b, const Point &);`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I think there's a question you aren't asking, such as how might I correctly test the direction of the point. In some cases the exact meaning of direction with respect to up/down and left/right might not be clearly defined.

Comment: `x = NULL;` is a mistake and may fail to compile. You mean `x = 0;`

Comment: @nwp can you explain what it would mean to compare a Point to a bool?  I doubt that is what OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an overloaded `operator==` that can work with `bool` and `Point`. The compiler tries to implicitly cast `bool` to `Point` but `Point` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `bool` and `Point` doesn't have an implicit cast `operator bool`. Create an overloaded `operator==`.

```
//in class definition
friend bool operator==(bool, const Point &);

//outside class definition
bool operator==(bool b, const Point &p) {
  return something;
}
```

Comment: In C++ member operator== won't take two arguments. Use `bool operator==(bool b)`

Comment: @JohnThoits in that situation `Finish` could not be used on the right-hand side as it is in OP code